# Having Trouble Integrated my stylesheet with HTML file

Tags: html, css

I am trying to figure out how to test how my code works but I cant seem to figure out why they wont link. They are in the same folder. I am also trying to add a facebook pixel and analytics to this page. Would I embed that code into my HTML file?

Thanks in Advance

Here is my code

Html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
        <title>Full Screen Landing Page</title>
        <link href rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <section class="intro">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content">
            <h1>Welcome To The Tribe</h1>
            <a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


</body>
</html>

@import url('https//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');
@import url('https//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald');


html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;

}

.intro{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    background: url() no-repeat 50% 50%;
    display: table;
    top: 0;
    background-size: cover;
}

.intro .inner{
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 100%;
    max-width:none;
}
```

Comment: you added href with out value

Answer (score 1):

it not `<link href rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

its

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
```

it read the initial `href` value as it is empty its not reading any css file

Comment: even this one works `<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" href>` ,  but not this 
`<link href rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">`

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need to have `href` before `rel` when you link your stylesheet. Also, you have a closing `html` tag but no opening `html` tag.

Answer (score 0):

Either put your custom css classes into the style.css file, or use style tag to include them, also you have duplicate href attribute inside link tag

```html
<head>
  <title>Full Screen Landing Page</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <style>
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;

    }

    .intro{
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
        margin: auto;
        background: url() no-repeat 50% 50%;
        display: table;
        top: 0;
        background-size: cover;
    }

    .intro .inner{
        display: table-cell;
        vertical-align: middle;
        width: 100%;
        max-width:none;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
    <section class="intro">
        <div class="inner">
            <div class="content">
            <h1>Welcome To The Tribe</h1>
            <a class="btn" href="#">Get Started</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>


</body>
```